# How do you sum up rows in Pandas based on conditions for multuples columns and remove the duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

First let me apologise for the long winded question. I've struggled to find an answer on Stackoverflow that addresses my specific issue.
I am new to Pandas and Python programming so I would appreciate all the help I can get.

I have a dataframe:

```
 ID            Name  Colour      Power  Year  Money (millions)
0   1234567      Tony Stark     Red     Genius  2020             20000
1   9876543    Peter Parker     Red     Spider  2021                75
2   1415926   Miles Morales   Green     Spider  2021                55
3   7777777    Dante Brisco    Blue     hybrid  2020                 3
4   4355681    Thor Odinson    Blue  Lightning  2020               655
5   1928374     Bruce Wayne  Yellow        Bat  2021             12000
6   5555555     Eddie Brock   Black   Symbiote  2021               755
7   8183822  Billie Butcher  Yellow          V  2021                34
8   6666654        Ian Wilm     Red  Lightning  2020                34
9   4241111    Harry Potter   Green     Wizard  2020                24
10  7765434        Blu Malk     Red     Wizard  2021                77
11  6464647         Yu Hant   Black     Wizard  2021                65
```

I want to create a new df that looks like this:

```
 **Colour    Total      Year 2020     Year 2021**
 Red        20186     20034          152
 Green      79        24             55 
 Blue       658       658            -------
 Yellow     12034     -------        12034
 Black      820       -------        820
```

Where the "Colour" column becomes the new primary key/ID, the duplicates are removed and the values per year are summed up along with an overall total. I have managed to sum up the Total but I am struggling to write a function that will sum up rows by year and than assign the sum to the respective colour. I would eventually like to Create new columns based on calculations from the Yearly columns (percentages)

Here is what I have after creating the DF from an excel file :

```
#This line helps me calculate the total from the old df. 
df['Total'] = df.groupby(['Colour'])['Money (millions)'].transform('sum') 

#This line drops the duplicates from the line above. So now I have a total column that matches the #Colours
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Colour'])
```

When I repeat the process for the Yearly column using the same technique it sums up the overall total for the whole year and assigns it to every colour.

I would eventually like to Create new columns based on calculations from the Yearly columns (percentages) e.g.

```
 new_df['Success Rate'] = new_df['Total'].apply(lambda x: (x/100)*33)
```

I'd be grateful for any help provided :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current output. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Colour', values='Money (millions)', columns='Year', aggfunc='sum', margins=True)
df
Out[1]: 
Year       2020     2021    All
Colour                         
Black       NaN    820.0    820
Blue      658.0      NaN    658
Green      24.0     55.0     79
Red     20034.0    152.0  20186
Yellow      NaN  12034.0  12034
All     20716.0  13061.0  33777
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. When I use your solution I get the desired output, but when I try applying a lambda function to each of the pivot table columns I get a key error. I figured the pivot table columns, 2020 and 2021, would be pandas columns. But when I try accessing them to apply the lambda I get an error saying the column name doesn't exist.

Comment: @A.Bux . The columns are multi-level. You can use ‘df.columns’ to figure out the column names.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is `pivot_table` with `margins`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Colour', columns='Year', 
               values='Money (millions)',
               aggfunc='sum',
               margins_name='Total',
               margins=True)
```

OUtput:

```
Year       2020     2021  Total
Colour                         
Black       NaN    820.0    820
Blue      658.0      NaN    658
Green      24.0     55.0     79
Red     20034.0    152.0  20186
Yellow      NaN  12034.0  12034
Total   20716.0  13061.0  33777
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. When I use your solution I get the desired output, but when I try applying a lambda function to each of the pivot table columns I get a key error. I figured the pivot table columns, 2020 and 2021, would be pandas columns. But when I try accessing them to apply the lambda I get an error saying the column name doesn't exist.